# Problem with using mysql query for month-on-month calculation and "stored procedure"

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql community server version 8.0.22

Summary -

1. I would like to calculate Month-on-Month as follow for existing data
2. I would like to add "trigger/stored procedure", for following months after I upload new month data, it should also update calculation in "MoM_calculation" table

total distinct count of - loyal customers ( customers from prev-month continue doing transaction in following month)

total distinct count of - dropout customers ( customers from prev-month no longer present in following month)

total distinct count of - new customers ( customers did not do transaction in prev-month but appears in following month)
[image]

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1154ec/2)  , I have prepared sql statements for table create and insert data in fiddle.**

Desired Output result table "MoM_calculation"

```
| year | month | total_customer | loyal | new | dropout |
|----- | ----- | -------------- | ----- | --- | ------- |
| 2021 | 01    | 5              | 0     | 5   | 0       |
| 2021 | 02    | 8              | 3     | 5   | 2       |
| 2021 | 03    | 7              | 1     | 6   | 7       |
| 2021 | 04    | 5              | 3     | 2   | 4       |
| 2021 | 05    | 5              | 0     | 5   | 5       |
| 2021 | 06    | 7              | 5     | 2   | 0       |
```

Here is Example of Daily Transaction Table

```
| _date    | customer_id | total |
|----------|-------------|-------|
|2021-01-13| c1          | 10.0  |
|2021-01-13| c2          | 20.0  |
|2021-01-14| c3          | 10.0  |
|2021-01-15| c4          | 14.0  |
|2021-01-16| c1          | 20.0  |
|2021-01-17| c5          | 15.0  |

|2021-02-13| c1          | 10.0  |
|2021-02-13| c2          | 20.0  |
|2021-02-14| c3          | 10.0  |
|2021-02-15| c6          | 14.0  |
|2021-02-16| c7          | 20.0  |
|2021-02-17| c8          | 15.0  |
|2021-02-17| c9          | 13.0  |
|2021-02-18| c10         | 15.0  |
|2021-02-19| c10         | 15.0  |
```

**Part 2**
Assuming

- daily transaction table has customer rank (rank on the day of purchase)
- customer ranking is only from 1 to 4

Sample Daily Transaction table

```
| _date    | customer_id | total |customer_rank|
|----------|-------------|-------|-------------|
|2021-01-13| c1          | 10.0  | rank1
|2021-01-13| c2          | 20.0  | rank2
|2021-01-14| c3          | 10.0  | rank3
|2021-01-15| c4          | 14.0  | rank4
|2021-01-16| c1          | 20.0  | rank1
|2021-01-17| c5          | 15.0  | rank2

|2021-02-13| c1          | 10.0  | rank2
|2021-02-13| c2          | 20.0  | rank3
|2021-02-14| c3          | 10.0  | rank4
|2021-02-15| c6          | 14.0  | rank3
|2021-02-16| c7          | 20.0  | rank2
|2021-02-17| c8          | 15.0  | rank1
|2021-02-17| c9          | 13.0  | rank2
|2021-02-18| c10         | 15.0  | rank4
|2021-02-19| c10         | 15.0  | rank4
```

The output that I would like to see (sorry since table is long, it won't fit in in one line)

```
| year | month | total_customer | loyal | new | dropout | (long table cont.)
|----- | ----- | -------------- | ----- | --- | ------- |
| 2021 | 01    | 5              | 0     | 5   | 0       |
| 2021 | 02    | 8              | 3     | 5   | 2       |

| loyal_rank1|loyal_rank2|loyal_rank3|loyal_rank4|        (long table cont.)    
|------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 0          | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| 0          | 1         | 1         | 1         |


| new_rank1|new_rank2|new_rank3|new_rank4|                (long table cont.)
|----------|---------|---------|---------|
| 1        | 2       | 1       | 1       | 

| dropout_rank1|dropout_rank2|dropout_rank3|dropout_rank4|
|--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
| 0            | 0           | 0           | 0           |
| 0            | 1           | 0           | 1           |
```

- as for first month, since there is only new only distinct "new" people ranks will be counted.
- starting from second month, there will be distinct "loyal, new, dropout"
  ranks will be counted.
- and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is that there is a lot of noise in the transaction table for this task. We see every single transaction by the same customer in the same month, while it suffices to know that the customer had at least one transaction in the month. But it's easy to boil that down:

```
select distinct year(_date), month(_date), customer_id from transactions;
```

Then we want to check whether the same customer had a transaction in the previous month. But while for 2021-04 we can just subtract 1 from the month and get 2021-03, we cannot do so for 2021-01, because there the month would have to switch from 1 to 12 and the year would have to change, too, in order to get to 2020-12. This makes joining the months difficult, but is also easy to solve. If we simply multiply a year by twelve and add the month we get the number 24252 for 2020-12 and the number 24253 for 2021-01. Adjacent numbers we can easily compare.

Then, we want a full outer join; customers present only in the previous month, customers present only in the current month, customers present in both months. But MySQL does not support full outer joins. The solution to this is to select all months and all customers and join on these combinations. This makes the query look a little clumsy, but it works.

```
with data as 
(
  select distinct
    year(_date) as year,
    month(_date) as month,
    year(_date) * 12 + month(_date) as num,
    customer_id
  from transactions
)
, months as (select distinct year, month, num from data)
, customers as (select distinct customer_id from data)
select
  m.year,
  m.month,
  count(this_month.num) as total_count,
  sum(prev_month.num is not null and this_month.num is not null) as loyal_ones,
  sum(prev_month.num is     null and this_month.num is not null) as new_ones,
  sum(prev_month.num is not null and this_month.num is     null) as dropouts
from months m
cross join customers c
left join data this_month on this_month.customer_id = c.customer_id and this_month.num = m.num
left join data prev_month on prev_month.customer_id = c.customer_id and prev_month.num = m.num - 1
group by m.year, m.month
order by m.year, m.month;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=199705ebab03a2f09254654d4d814944

Comment: hank you for replying. I have added this before the last line "group by m.year, m.month" But in month 2, total should be 8, because total is (distinct), loyal 3, new 5, dropout 5. Logic is new + loyal =  total current month , loyal + dropout = total prev month.

Comment: Hi, sorry about the missing `GROUP BY` clause. I also missed the `DISTINCT` in the first CTE. I explained on the top of my question that this is what we use to get to the data we want, but then I missed that when writing the query. At last there was a comma missing. Now it should work.

Comment: Yes, it works flawlessly for first part. Now I need to figure out how to turn this into trigger, so that every month when I insert new monthly data, it will auto calculate and update it into "MoM_calculation" table.

Comment: could you explain this line "which column you are trying to sum 
"sum(prev_month.num is not null and this_month.num is not null) as loyal_ones"

Comment: @Zaw Lynn Htut: In MySQL true equals 1 and false equals 0. So, `SUM( <boolean expression> )` counts for how many rows the expression is true. I am counting all customers that had transactions in both the grouped month and the previous one.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I have a lot from you. Also I have tried to use the code you have provided for part 2 of the question (i just added), but it broke the output. Especially "loyal, new, and dropout" counts are no longer correct.

Comment: @Zaw Lynn Htut: You added expressions like `sum(this_month.customer_rank = 'rank1' and prev_month.num is not null and this_month.num is not null) as loyal_rank1,` and it broke the existing counts???

Comment: yes, here is dbfiddle (but in dbfiddle it says cust_rank is ambiguous) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90fd066a1330d56b4bdcc7b1ae31702b

Comment: @Zaw Lynn Htut: Because `cust_rank` exists twice. Once in `prev_month` and once in `this_month`. You want `this_month.cust_rank`.

Comment: Once again, thank you very much. I forgot to add this_month and prev_month in dbfiddle, my original code has those. Also I found the issue in my datasource, customer ranks has null values. I replace nulls with "undefine" it's working again now.